# Инструкция if не выполняется при очевидном условии

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка, динамические-массивы, devc++

Впервые на этом сайте. Если что не так оформил - пожалуйста, извините и укажите - исправлюсь. На всякий случай скинул весь код. Проблема в функции вывода - **void out**. Сравнивая с функцией сортировки (int sort), можно увидеть, что начало у них совершенно идентичное (значение j в void out никак не влияет на успешность работы функции). Разница в том, что сортировка выполняется при обоих условиях, а вывод работает только при втором условии (m не равно 1, то есть элементов в массиве больше, чем 1). При первом условии (m=1), программа просто вылетает. Я не могу понять, почему.

```
//Задача: ввести массив с клавиатуры;
//выбрать чётные элементы с нечётным индексом; вывести их сумму;
//отсортировать по убыванию; вывести отсортированный массив
#include <locale.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int i, j;

int * org(int *a, int &n)
{
    cout<<"Введите количество элементов массива: ", cin>>n;
    a=new int[n];
    cout<<"Введите "<<n<<" элементов массива: "<<endl;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        cout<<i<<": ", cin>>a[i];
    cout<<"Исходный массив: "<<endl;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        cout<<" a["<<i<<"]="<<a[i];
    return a;
}

int * process(int *a, int *b, int &m, int n)
{
    int sum, flag=0;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        if (a[i]%2==0)
            flag++;
    if (flag==n)
        {
            cout<<"В массиве не найдены нечётные элементы:"<<endl;
            for(i=0; i<n; i++)
                cout<<" a["<<i<<"]="<<a[i];
            delete []a;
            exit(0);
        }
    else
        for(i=0, sum=0; i<n; i++)
            if ((i%2==0)&&(a[i]%2!=0))
            {
                sum+=a[i];
                m++;
            }
        cout<<"Сумма нечётных элементов массива с чётным индексом: "<<sum<<endl;
        b=new int[m];
        cout<<"Массив нечётных чисел: "<<endl;
        for(i=0; i<n; i++)
            if ((i%2==0)&&(a[i]%2!=0))
                {
                    b[j]=a[i];
                    cout<<" b["<<j<<"]="<<b[j];
                    j++;
                }
    return b;
}

int * sort(int *b, int m)
{
    int temp;
    j=0;
    if (m==1)
    {
        cout<<"Сортировка невозможна - массив содержит только один элемент:"<<endl
            <<" b["<<j<<"]="<<b[j];
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        for(i=m; i>0; i--)
            for(j=0; j<i; j++)
                if (b[j]<b[j+1])
                {
                    temp=b[j];
                    b[j]=b[j+1];
                    b[j+1]=temp;
                }
    cout<<"Массив отсортирован";
    }
    return b;
}

void out(int *a, int *b, int m)
{
    if (m==1) //если количество элементов = 1
    {
        cout<<"Массив содержит единственный элемент:"<<endl
            <<" b["<<j<<"]="<<b[j];
        delete []a;
        delete []b;
        exit(0); //то написали это и завершили программу
    }
    else //иначе вывели весь массив
    {
        cout<<"Отсортированный массив: "<<endl;
        for(j=0; j<m; j++)
            cout<<" b["<<j<<"]="<<b[j];
    }
}

void clear(int *a, int *b)
{
    delete []a;
    delete []b;
    cout<<"Память освобождена";
    exit(0);
}

main()
{   setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int *a, *b;
    int n, m=0;
    char key;
    do
    {
        system("cls");
        cout<<"Выберите инструкцию: "<<endl
            <<"1: Организация массива"<<endl
            <<"2: Найти сумму нечётных элементов с чётным индексом"<<endl
            <<"3: Отсортировать новосозданный массив по убыванию"<<endl
            <<"4: Показать отсортированный массив"<<endl
            <<"0: Освободить память и завершить программу"<<endl;
        cin>>key;
        switch(key)
        {
            case '1': a=org(a, n); break;
            case '2': b=process(a, b, m, n); break;
            case '3': b=sort(b, m); break;
            case '4': out(a, b, m); break;
            case '0': clear(a, b);
            default: cout<<"Некорректный ввод";
        }
        cout<<endl;
        system("pause");
    } while (key!='0');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Инструкция `if` прекрасно выполняется. Непонятно, почему вы пришли к выводу, что она "не выполняется".

Потому ваша программа и вылетает, что внутри этой инструкции `if` вы обращаетесь к `b[j]` через нулевой указатель `b`.

(При этом, кстати, в упор не ясно чему в этот момент равно `j`. Откуда у вас возникла странная идея сделать `i` и `j` глобальными переменными?)

Ваш указатель `b` стал нулевым когда в функции `sort` при `m == 1` вы сделали `return 0;` (и заодно отправили весь массив `b` в утечку памяти). Зачем вы сделали этот `return 0;`? В чем тут идея?

---

И что такое `main()`??? Куда подевался тип возвращаемого значения функции?

Comment: Это не критика, а мнение:   не очень то хорошо смотрится ответ, где одни вопросы....

Comment: `i` и `j` - глобальные потому, что используются в нескольких функциях по порядку, и их значение после выполнения каждой функции становится новым, которое используется в следующей функции, выбранной в меню. Я правильно мыслю, так должно быть? Я только-только начал C/C++ осваивать. `return 0` исправил на `return b` в функции `sort` - заработало, спасибо! "Идея" была в том, чтобы просто сразу завершить функцию, но сыграла моя невнимательность :( . А в `main` почему должно что-то возвращаться? `main` - это просто меню. Окончательный "возврат" и выход происходят при выборе `'0'`.

Comment: @ДанилПузырёв Я не вижу у вас в коде ни одного места, где бы значение `i` или `j` из предыдущего вызова использовалось в следующем. О каком "которое используется в следующей функции" вы ведете речь? Это как бы имеет место в вызове `out`, но это ошибка. Поэтому мне все равно не ясно, почему `i` и `j` сделаеы глобальными. И все функции в С++ обязаны быть объявлены с явно указанным типом возвращаемого значения. `main()` - это не компилируемо.

Comment: @AnT Нуу.. 1) организация: там используется `i` и нарастает по ходу цикла; 2) обработка: там цикл обнуляет `i` и снова наращивает, а `j` присваивается значение `i`; 3) сортировка: вот здесь я нарочно написал `j=0`, потому что программа не работает при первом условии, а иначе - `j` наращивается; 4) вывод: эта `j` с конкретным значением после использования в предыдущей функции передаётся в первое условие, иначе (во втором условии) `j` обнуляется в цикле. Я изначально не так выразился, прошу прощения. Надеюсь, сейчас понятно объяснил. На счёт `main` - не знаю, в Dev-C++ компилируется и работает.

Comment: @AnT программа работает только, если инструкции выбирать по порядку, поэтому `i` и `j` поставлены вот так. если я правильно Вас понял.